# Vue with Browserify on Runtime only build

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I've been trying to figure this one out but I always get

> [Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the
>   template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates
>   into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.  (found in
>   )

I'm using laravel 5.2 with browserify with elixir and vue 2.2.2

I'm trying to display a simple view

this is my app.js

> import Vue from 'vue';
>   import Test from './components/Test.vue';
>
> new Vue({     el : '.container',  render: h => h(Test) })

Test.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="view">
        <h1>{{msg}} </h1>
    </div>
</template>


<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
    data (){
        return {
            msg : 'This is Vue'
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style>
    div.view{
        padding:2em;
        position: relative;
    }


</style>
```

Comment: What was the answer?

Comment: @justin.m.chase I don't have the answer. I want to use the runtime only build since it is lightweight. And no one's been able to give me the answer.

Comment: I actually managed to figure this out but I am using webpack instead of browserify. The problem seems to be that if you're just using `require('vue')` the file that the default resultion algorithm goes to doesn't have, as the error says, a template compiler. If you're running it in node for the server renderer then it works but if you try to webpack it for a browser its missing.

So what you need to do is to essentially require vue.common.js instead, I can do this in webpack by adding this to the config:

`resolve: { alias: { 'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' }}`

Comment: This question should be deleted. I already figured this one out.

Comment: I think its fine to leave it, I found this one sooner than I found the actual solution and the comments here will help someone if they have the same problem hopefully.

Comment: I would suggest them to use webpack for bundling as it's more powerful, thus using vue-loader

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this might help. This is an example of my setup. I'm also using `VueRouter`.

app.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import App from './components/App.vue';
import Home from './components/Home.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [{
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },
// .. others
});

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: createEle => createEle(App)
}).$mount('#app-container');
```

App.vue:

```html
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <p>
            <router-link to="/foo">Foo</router-link>
            <router-link to="/foo2">Foo 2</router-link>
        </p>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    // empty
}
</script>
```

index.html:

```html
<div id="app-container"></div>
```

I hope that helps.

Ref: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215#issuecomment-292071919

Answer (score 1):

Are you using laravel-elixir-vueify? Try using laravel-elixir-vue-2 instead..you can also try to set the vue.common.js inside "browser" of package.json (i'm using npm with gulp and browserify)..like:

```
"browse": { "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js" }
```